# The Coin Conundrum

Tags: weighing, coins

You are a coin collector who recently acquired a set of rare antique coins. The set contains 14 coins - 12 are authentic but 2 are counterfeit. The real coins each weigh 1 oz, while the fakes each weigh 1.1 oz.

You have an accurate digital scale, but it can only measure the weight of up to 3 coins at a time. What is the minimum number of weighings needed to guarantee you can identify both counterfeit coins?

Comment: Did you make this puzzle yourself?

Answer (score 0):

> I thought it was 8. You weight n=[3,3,3,3,2] coins that (in the worst case/ least efficient/ requiring most weighings) they would weigh w=[3,3,3.1,3,2.1] oz.